# Create many partitions as a result of a select statement in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Here is a table of phone numbers named `phone_number`:

| phone_number | country_code | owner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07911 123456 | 44 | Ada |
| 08912 654321 | 44 | Thomas |
| 06 12 34 56 78 | 33 | Jonathan |
| 06 87 65 43 21 | 33 | Arthur |

Let's say we want to partition this table by country code, therefore creating this table `phone_number_bis`

```sql
CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis (
                phone_number VARCHAR,
                country_code INTEGER,
                owner VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (phone_number, country_code)
) PARTITION BY LIST(country_code)
```

Loading the content of `phone_number` into `phone_number_bis` will produce the following error:

```sql
INSERT INTO phone_number_bis( phone_number, country_code, owner)
SELECT  phone_number, country_code, owner
FROM phone_number;

ERROR: no partition of relation "phone_number_bis" found for row
Partition key of the failing row contains (country_code) = (44)
```

Is there a SQL command that could create all necessary partitions before loading data into `phone_number_bis`, not knowing the content of the `country_code` column in advance ?

**NB**: as [Franck Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) pointed out, partitioning the table may not be relevant for storing phone numbers. This is an example made in order to make a complex problem more understable.

Comment: No. But it is easy to write a query that would use `format()` to created the required SQL statements.

Comment: There is a standard list of country codes, you could use that to create all partitions. But before you do so, do you really have to partition this data? Most countries are so small, that wouldn't make sense. Maybe the top-10 countries make sense, that would be already half of the world population.

Comment: I used the phone number example in order not to disclose a schema describing a complex business logic, where partitioning is required and the list of possible partitions is not known in advance. Thank you for questioning the necessity of partitioning as it could avoid further technical problems.

Comment: If you are partitioning just for the sake of partitioning, you can do it by hash instead of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) and [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes) said, it cannot be done only with a SQL command.
A PL/pgSQL procedure seems to be required here :

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE partition_number INTEGER;
BEGIN
   FOR partition_number IN SELECT DISTINCT(country_code) FROM phone_number
   LOOP 
        EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis_%s PARTITION OF phone_number_bis FOR VALUES IN (%s)',  partition_number,  partition_number);
   END LOOP ;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

INSERT INTO phone_number_bis( phone_number, country_code, owner)
SELECT  phone_number, country_code, owner
FROM phone_number; -- No error as partitions have been created before insertion
```

Answer (score 1):

If your client is `psql`, you can use `\gexec` to make it run a query and then run each result as a new command.  So then you would need to write one query which output a text string containing a suitable CREATE TABLE statement for each distinct country_code.  To do it entirely on the server side, you could use pl/pgsql to do much the same thing, constructing a string and then using dynamic sql to EXECUTE the string.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a SQL command that could create all necessary partitions
> before loading data into phone_number_bis, not knowing the content of
> the country_code column in advance ?
> You can use DEFAULT partition, then split partition from DEFAULT.

```
begin;
create table phone_number(phone_number text,country_code integer, owner text);
insert into phone_number select 'dummy_' || (random()::numeric(10,4)),
    120 + i,'owner'||i from generate_series(1, 5) g(i);
insert into phone_number select 'dummy_' || (random()::numeric(10,4)),
    220+i,'owner'||i from generate_series(1, 5) g(i);
insert into phone_number select 'dummy_' || (random()::numeric(10,4)), 1 ,'owner'||i from generate_series(1, 20) g(i);
select string_agg(distinct (country_code::text),', ' order by (country_code::text)) 
from phone_number 
where country_code > 99 and country_code < 201;
commit;
```

---

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis (
    phone_number text,country_code integer,OWNER text,
    PRIMARY KEY (phone_number, country_code)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (country_code);

CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis_01 PARTITION OF phone_number_bis
FOR VALUES IN (1);

CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis_2_300 PARTITION OF phone_number_bis
FOR VALUES IN (121, 122, 123, 124, 125);

CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis_default PARTITION OF phone_number_bis DEFAULT;

INSERT INTO phone_number_bis (phone_number, country_code, OWNER)
SELECT phone_number, country_code,OWNER FROM phone_number;
COMMIT;
```

now split the partition from default partition create an new partition for values in 200 to 300.

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE phone_number_bis DETACH PARTITION phone_number_bis_default;
ALTER TABLE phone_number_bis_default RENAME TO phone_number_bis_default_old;
CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis_200_300 PARTITION OF phone_number_bis
FOR VALUES IN (221, 222, 223, 224, 225);
CREATE TABLE phone_number_bis_default PARTITION OF phone_number_bis DEFAULT;
INSERT INTO phone_number_bis (phone_number, country_code, OWNER)
SELECT phone_number, country_code, OWNER FROM phone_number_bis_default_old;
COMMIT;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html
Quote:

> Choosing the target number of partitions that the table should be
> divided into is also a critical decision to make. Not having enough
> partitions may mean that indexes remain too large and that data
> locality remains poor which could result in low cache hit ratios.
> However, dividing the table into too many partitions can also cause
> issues. **Too many partitions can mean longer query planning times and
> higher memory consumption during both query planning and execution**, as
> further described below.

Quote:

> Another reason to be concerned about having a large number of
> partitions is that the server's memory consumption may grow
> significantly over time, especially if many sessions touch large
> numbers of partitions. That's because **each** partition requires its
> metadata to be loaded into the local memory of **each** session that
> touches it.

More partition, will consume more memory, there is an case: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/PH0PR11MB5191F459DCB44A91682FE8C8D6409%40PH0PR11MB5191.namprd11.prod.outlook.com#86aaad1ddd6350efc062c2dd79a31821

Comment: It seems that writing your sql instructions you know which partitions to create while writing the query. Which cannot apply to the problem I described.
Also I get your point concerning the risks of creating too many partitions, but in this use case only 1 partition is read for every query made to the table. A user is never interested in querying phone numbers from more than one countries.

Comment: @NoanCloarec You just need based on how many rows properly set the number of partition. and default partition can help you add new partitions.